# How to write mouseover with PageFactory

Tags: selenium, drop-down-menu, mouseover, pageobjects

My code should click on the value from the drop-down menu, I have this code:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Product Category']"));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(element).perform();
waitForElementToBeDisplayed(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='iMacs']")), 500);
WebElement subElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='iMacs']"));
action.moveToElement(subElement);
action.click();
action.perform();
```

I tried to rewrite your code, and I write with PageFactory:

```
WebElement element = mouse_over_product_category;
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(element).perform();
waitForElementToBeDisplayed(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='iMacs']")), 500);
WebElement subElement = link_iMacs;
action.moveToElement(subElement);
action.click();
action.perform();
```

My error is:

```
org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

Can someone help me how to write. I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Product Category']"));        
String mouseOver = "var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');" +
                            "evObj.initMouseEvent(\"mouseover\",true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);" +
                            "arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evObj);";


   ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(mouseOver, element);
```

This one is with JavaScript

Comment: Outputs this to me: Cannot resolve symbol 'GlobalVars '

Comment: That was just my local instance of WebDriver. Use the updated one. Should work.

Comment: Your code works, but opens the first item in the drop-down menu, and I want to click to another.

Answer (score 0):

There are more than these 2 ways to do so..

try accomplishing what you need by using these:

```
//Conventional Way- Identifying the Select Menu Box and sending the text desired to select either by Text or Index or by value



    WebElement elDropDownItem = driver.findElement(By.xpath(""));

                if (elDropDownItem != null) {
                    Select comboBox = new Select(elDropDownItem);

//Either of these 3 should work SelectBy-- should work
                        comboBox.selectByVisibleText(MenuItemText);
                        break;
            //OR        
                        comboBox.selectByIndex(Integer
                                .parseInt(MenuItemIndex));
                        break;
            //OR        
                        comboBox.selectByValue(MenuItemValue);
                        break;
                    }
```

Another way:

```
//Clicking the down arrow and then clicking on the Select Item you desire
            WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.xpath("downArrow"));
            element.click();

WebElement element1= driver.findElement(By.xpath("selectMenuItem"));
            element1.click();
```